# ckeditor jquery integration

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, fckeditor

can some one guide me to a good tutorial for jquery ckeditor integration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the [CKEditor Devolopers Guide](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/jQuery_Adapter)?